# "%2==0" is too long, can it be shorter?

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
int oszthatosag(int t[],int d){int j=0;for(int i=0;d>i;i++)if(t[i]%2==0)j++;return j;}
```

which is

```
int oszthatosag(int t[], int d) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; d > i; i++)
        if (t[i] % 2 == 0)
            j++;
    return j;
}
```

The Limit is 83 byte. (for the length)
The input and function name can't be changed.
Right now it is 86 byte long. So it's too long. (It looks like this, because the space and line break characters are counted too).

Comment: `if(t[i]%2==0)j++` -> `j+=1-t[i]%2`

Comment: Sorry, solving Code Golf problems is not really what we do here. The whole point of those competitions is for you to figure it out yourself. But we write readable code here.

Comment: Added whitespace for readability. Aside: idiomatically, `i<d` would be better than `d>i`.

Comment: Save one byte with `int t[]` changed to `int *t`.

Comment: You don't need variable for index, just use the pointer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: your proposition does not work for odd negative numbers. `j+=!(t[i]%2)` is one byte longer but still shorter than `if(t[i]%2==0)j++`

Comment: This question is somewhat off topic, but can serve for pedagogical purposes: what does this code do and how can I rewrite it with fewer operations?  Note that `t[i] % 2 == 0` tests if `t[i]` is even... `t[i] % 2` can have 3 different values: `0`, `1` for positive odd integers, and `-1` for odd negative integers, which is good to know.

Comment: Start with `int j = d;`, replace the whole `if` statement with `j -= t[i] % 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas for your divisibility function (**oszthatóság** means *divisibility* in hungarian):

- `int t[]` can be changed to `int*t`: 1 byte
- `if(t[i]%2==0)j++;` boils down to `j+=!(t[i]%2);`: 4 bytes
- declaring `i` and `j` together and intializing them together:

`int j=0;for(int i=0;d>i;i++)` -> `int j=0,i=0;for(;d>i;i++)` : 3 bytes

- incrementing `i` inside the loop body: 1 more byte
- cosmetics: use `while(i<d)` instead of `for(;d>i;)`

Here is the resulting function:

```
int oszthatosag(int*t,int d){int i=0,j=0;while(i<d)j+=!(t[i++]%2);return j;}
```

One more idea: this function computes the number of even numbers in the array. If `d>=0`, this number is the same as `d` minus the number of odd numbers, which can be computed with fewer bytes:

```
int oszthatosag(int*t,int d){int i=0,j=d;while(i<d)j-=t[i++]&1;return j;}
```

*@dimich* hinted that `i` is not needed:

```
int oszthatosag(int*t,int d){int j=d;while(d-->0)j-=*t++&1;return j;}
```

Comment: The OP's function computes the number of even numbers in the array. If d>=0, this number is the same as d minus the number of odd numbers, which can be computed with fewer bytes:

Comment: Oh neat, did not see that in the code, my bad